# Python: Converting Unicode code point filenames to strings

Tags: python, unicode, winrar

I'm using Python's zipfile module to extract .zip files which can contain files with Unicode filenames. WinZip and 7-Zip archives work fine, but WinRAR encodes the filenames a little differently. Say I create a zip file containing a file called "-★-私-", and extract it with this:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'r') as zf:
    zf.extractall(extract_dir)
```

This extracts "-★-私-" as "-#U2605-#U79c1-". The ZipInfo object's filename isn't encoded, it's just a regular ASCII string containing the output filename.

I'd like to translate the string, which contains the Unicode code points U-2605 and U-79C1, to a useful, outputtable Unicode string. So I wrote this, but it doesn't convert the characters properly:

```
string = codePoints.replace('#U', '\\u').encode('utf-8')
```

Anyway, where have I stepped wrong here? I'm not getting the same result I would get if I did:

```
string = '-\u2605-\u79c1-'.encode('utf-8')
```

(Assuming Python 3; in Python 2, I would preface that previous string with a "u" character.)

Comment: This might be because '\\u2605' isn't the same as '\u2605'.

Comment: If you want to get hacky, you _could_ actually do this step, and then follow it up by a step that decodes with the `unicode_escape` codec (which will turn all those `\\u2605` sequences into `\u2605` characters). Of course that will fail if you had any actual Unicode characters (as you would from more standard zipfiles), so you need to do a fancy dance to handle all of the stupid edge cases…

Comment: Yeah, my mistake with the \\u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
>>> cp = '#U79c1'
>>> chr(int(cp[2:],16))
'私'
```

For instance:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import re

def makeNice(s):
    return re.subn('(#U[0-9a-f]{4})', lambda cp: chr(int(cp.groups()[0][2:],16)), s) [0]

a = '-#U2605-#U79c1-'
print(a, makeNice(a))
```

prints

```
-#U2605-#U79c1- -★-私-
```

Comment: Looks great, thanks; I considered regexes but wasn't sure if they were the best solution. Note that unichr() must be used instead of chr() on Python 2.